# How to catch error in asynchronous Proxy/Reflect trap

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I catch an error that gets thrown asynchronously by `Reflect.get(target, name, receiver)` within the Proxy handler?

I'm using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) to wrap an **API** class, so that I can catch any Network exceptions and gracefully display error messages to the user.

```js
//Wrapper.js

let handler = {
  get: (target, name, receiver) => {
    try {
      Reflect.get(target, name, receiver); //throws Error asynchronously
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('caught error', e);
    }
};

export default new Proxy(new API(), handler);
```

```js
//App.js

import Wrapper from './Wrapper';

Wrapper.asyncFunction(); //throws uncaught Error
```

```js
//API.js

class API {
  get user() {
    return new User()
  }
}
```

```js
//User.js

class User {

  /**
   * List all users
   */
  all() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(new Error('Network error'));
    });
  }
}
```

When an error is thrown, inside Reflect.get() "caught error" never gets printed and remains uncaught.

Comment: "Thrown asynchronously" meaning within a Promise? You could attach a `catch` handler to the return value of `Reflect.get(...)`.

Comment: You cannot "throw asynchronously". All you can do is "return a promise that will get rejected".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the call to the return value of `Reflect.get(...)` (the actual API method) in a new Promise, catch any errors, log them, and then pass them on again. Similarly if there are no errors simply resolve the outer Promise.

```
let handler = {
  get: (target, name, receiver) => {
    return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const apiMethod = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
      const boundApiMethod = apiMethod.bind(target);

      boundApiMethod(...args).then(resolve, (e) => {
        console.log('caught error', e);
        reject(e);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Your current code is not catching the error because asynchronous functions are not executed in-place, so the error is thrown outside of the try block.

Edit: an alternative approach that doesn't use a Promise constructor:

```
let handler = {
  get: (target, name, receiver) => {
    return (...args) => {
      return Reflect
        .get(target, name, receiver)
        .apply(target, args)
        .catch((e) => { console.log('caught error', e) });
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should have mentioned that Reflect.get() also can return a function that is not a Promise. An error is then thrown where .catch() is undefined.

Comment: Under what circumstances would it not return a Promise? Please add the code for `Wrapper.asyncFunction` to your Q. I suggest that you amend the API to always return a Promise, otherwise you cannot reliably catch the error.

Comment: Actually, even if **Wrapper** has only functions that return promises, adding a .catch() to Reflect still throws the error that .catch is undefined. See https://jsfiddle.net/geh2k153/3/

Comment: That's because you aren't invoking the function returned from `Reflect.get`. :-)

Comment: [How about this?](http://jsbin.com/dipuwesaye/1/edit?html,js,console) Catches the error internally, logs it, then passes the result on via a new Promise.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - Your example works on jsbin, however, when I put it into my own code, the function that gets called by Reflect.get() inside API.js now does not have `this` defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121947/discussion-between-sdgluck-and-mastergalen).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Reflect does not seem to work when trying to call a function of a class instance in the property of the API class. E.g. calling Wrapper.user.all() throws the error that it's not a function, even though if I console.log the wrapper right before calling it, it's showing that the function is defined in the `[[Target]]` property of the Proxy instance

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I've added an alternative. :-)

Comment: really good reply, i was able to use your second code block to chain an `expect(code)` method to the `axios` package to mimic `supertest`. thanks!!